# How to clear a jpeg image?

Tags: delphi

How to clear a TJPEGImage image?

The `JPG.Width := 0` trick won't work.
Also I don't want to create an empty bitmap (0x0 pixels) and assign it to the jpeg.

Comment: If you don't want to free the object, but you don't want it to occupy memory anymore, then what *do* you want to keep?

Comment: @Rob. It will be reused later. Multiple times. Anyway, the reason doesn't matter that much. I just plain curious if the image can be cleared WITHOUT consuming additional resources (creating new objects as bummi suggests).

Comment: I too can't see what you are keeping if you want to remove everything. What's left when the image has gone? What state is there?

Comment: Suppose you *can* "clear" the image. Can you give an example of what you would do with that object afterward? Knowing what you plan to do once you arrive somewhere can help us find the proper route to get there.

Comment: I just discovered that TImage.Picture.LoadFromFile('') will clear the image. Cool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might use something like this (the interposed class is used here to access the protected methods):

```
type
  TJPEGImage = class(jpeg.TJPEGImage);

implementation

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  JPEGImage: TJPEGImage;
begin
  JPEGImage := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    // this should recreate the internal bitmap
    JPEGImage.NewBitmap;
    // this should recreate the internal image stream
    JPEGImage.NewImage;
    // here the memory used by the image should be released
  finally
    JPEGImage.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use FreeAndNil and keep the image empty...

```
Procedure EmptyJPG(jpg:TJpegImage);
var
 j:TJpegImage;
begin
  j := TJpegImage.Create;
  try
    jpg.Assign(j);
  finally
    j.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Altar: I think you mean 'in my question/in the original question', and not 'in the OP'. The OP (=original poster) is you.

Comment: This isn't a solution. It's no more efficient than freeing and recreating the original JPEGImage (and is actually less so, as you've now created a new object for no reason other than to throw it away). While the original question makes no sense, your proposed solution makes even less sense. (Not downvoting, BTW; just don' t see the point.)

Comment: @KenWhite, full agree, the only reason I would see might bee something like:
begin
    EmptyJPG(FMyMyReadOnlyPropertyJPEG);          Showmessage('set before: ' + IntToStr(FMyMyReadOnlyPropertyJPEG.CompressionQuality))
end;

Answer (score 0):

place the Tshape component on background on TImage component

```
Image1 : Timage
.
.
Image1.Picture.Graphic.Assign(nil);
```

Comment: How is this related to my question?